# Using the script variable OMP_NUM_THREADS in the program source files

Tags: c++, openmp, pbs

If I'm running C++ code on a cluster, is it possible to use the value of OMP_NUM_THREADS in my program? For example, suppose I have two .cpp files main.cpp and func.cpp, where func.cpp is written in parallel using OpenMP. I want to be able to define the number of threads once (in the script below) and not have to define it again in func.cpp.

```
#!/bin/bash

#PBS -S /bin/bash
#PBS -l walltime=00:10:00
#PBS -l select=1:ncpus=4:mem=2gb
#PBS -q QName
#PBS -N Name
#PBS -o Results/output.txt
#PBS -e Results/error.txt
#PBS -m abe -M email@address

module purge
module load intel-compiler/11.1.073

export OMP_NUM_THREADS=4

cd $WORKDIR

./myprog
```

Comment: Your program doesn't use the value automatically?

Comment: Nope, it didn't recognise it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [omp_set_num_threads()](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libgomp/omp_005fset_005fnum_005fthreads.html) to set the number of threads in your program.
To use the value externally specified by `OMP_NUM_THREADS`, you'll need to read it from the environment variables using [std::getenv](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/program/getenv).  Be sure to 1) convert the string result to a number and 2) sanitize the value in case it's unset.

The pseudocode will look something like:

```
unsigned int thread_qty = std::max(atoi(std::getenv("OMP_NUM_THREADS")), 1);
omp_set_num_threads(thread_qty);
```

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly what I wanted. Can you do the same with functions? For example, I actually have two versions of func.cpp: the parallel OpenMP version (func_parallel.cpp) and a serial version (func_serial.cpp). I would like to be able to have another script file for my serial version, which specifies that I want to use func_serial.cpp instead of func_parallel.cpp. Is this possible?

Answer (score 2):

If you set the environment variable `OMP_NUM_THREADS` to some value, and never touch the number of threads in your code (e.g. via `omp_set_num_threads()`), your code will use

- Dynamic adjustment is disabled (`OMP_DYNAMIC=FALSE`/`omp_set_dynamic(0)`): The code will use `OMP_NUM_THREADS` threads
- Dynamic adjustment is enabled (`OMP_DYNAMIC=TRUE`/`omp_set_dynamic(1)`): The code will use **up to** `OMP_NUM_THREADS` threads (but might use less).

So, just use `OMP_NUM_THREADS` and don't specify any number of threads in the source code.